# Nested backticks in cshrc alias

Tags: shell, command-line, alias, csh

I am trying to create an alias to go to a specific directory depending on the directory I am currently in. I am trying to use the following as an alias:

```
set m=`pwd`; set n=`echo $m | cut -d/ -f 1-6`; cd $n/a/b/c
```

Even this is not working. When I source the `.cshrc`, it says:

> m: Undefined variable.

I know it's stupid to create a variable in an alias as it might accidentally overwrite a variable under use. I tried using nested backticks (`) but that does not seem to work, and neither does `$(.)` in `.cshrc`.

Any smarter solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the variables:

```
cd "`pwd | cut -d/ -f 1-6`/a/b/c"
```